# UV Unwrapping a Modified Model

Tags: uv, faces

I modified an existing model by removing unwanted vertices, then selecting surrounding vertices and creating faces one triangle at a time (By pressing 'F').

On UV unwrapping the mesh, the faces which were added by me seem to stretch from the very bottom left of the map, shown below.

[image: UV map of faces added by me starts on bottom left then stretches.]

How do I create a face so it appears on the UV map as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of distortion often happens when you modify the mesh that has been unwrapped. You can try to unwrap once again after modification, or ***pin*** the vertices of islands you want to stay in the same position and then unwrap. In *UV/Image Editor* window select all the vertices except the distorted one and press <kbd>P</kbd>.
[image]

Now select the whole mesh (<kbd>A</kbd>) in a *3D View* window and unwrap it. Being in *UV/Image Editor* window unpin all using <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> shortcut. The modified vertices should come back to their places.
[image]

Comment: Here is what happened on my side when I followed those steps: http://i.imgur.com/BKlX6vJ.gif

Comment: After a pinning step, select the whole mesh with 'A' and then unwrap.

Comment: That is what I did, you can see this on the left side of that gif.

Comment: When I look at your .gif I see that the vertex/vertices in the down left corner of a UV/Image Editor window is/are not selected. Press 'A' in the UV/Image Editor window and then unwrap.

Comment: Right, I did that wrong. But it still doesn't seem to want to work. http://i.imgur.com/IXVKpXa.gif

Comment: Hmmm...Very strange behaviour. I have no idea what's causing that. Btw When you unwrap the mesh without pinning, how does it look like?

Comment: When I unwrap without pinning it looks like an asteroid burning in the atmosphere (everything is decreased and clusteres off-center, with a trail of stretched triangles). I guess Blender just doesn't like me. Thank you for all your help.