# UV mapping after importing

Tags: uv, import

I am working on level design in Google SketchUp. I use Blender to create and edit the UV map of the final mesh that I use in the game engine. I am sure I will still add details to the level after I have UV mapped it, but that would mean UV mapping it all over again face by face, and link faces to materials again because the new level would have to be imported again. So TL;DR:

1. I'm exporting the Google SketchUp model as COLLADA
2. Importing it into Blender and UV mapping it

--- WHAT I WANT --

3. Changing the model in SketchUp and re-importing it without having to UV map the whole thing again.

I am also considering continuing the level design in Blender, but SketchUp is way faster, so I would like to stick to it. I hope I was clear enough about what my problem is.
Thank you for your time :)

Comment: If you mean that second time you want to continue unwrapping model in Blender, you can pin existing vertices on UV map. They will stay in place even when unwrapped. See more about pinning - [UV unwrapping a modified model](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23354/uv-unwrapping-a-modified-model)

Comment: The model isn't modified in Blender, but in SketchUp and then re-imported. That means that as far as Blender knows, it's a totally new mesh and has nothing to do with the old one.

Comment: What are you using Blender for in this case ?

Comment: UV mapping the faces of the final mesh, removing doubles, dissolving faces

Comment: For import / export use some format which supports UV maps. Once imported in Blender open UV map which should be stored with it, pin everything there and you should be able to unwrap further. Pinned verts won't be changed. Export again in that format.

Comment: Google SketchUp cannot import any format that supports UV mapping and at the same time preserves my model(it only supports .3ds, but that triangulates all my faces)