# Can I adapt UV map after geometry change?

Tags: texturing, uv

Is there any way to repair a pre-existing UV map after deleting some unnecessary faces and replacing them by a simpler geometry? Everything of the old mapping works fine. Unfortunately my new vertices are all positioned at the bottom left of the UV map. This leads to rather odd textures in the front of my car model. (See screenshot below reference.) Unfortunately I don't understand yet how customized uv-mapping works. I just want to adapt pre-existing models.
I expect I would need to add the new faces to the proper selection group. But how can I do that?
[image: The red areas mark the problematic parts in 3D view and UV map.]

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23354/uv-unwrapping-a-modified-model

Comment: The guide sounds promising, but unfortunately the displaced vertices in the UV map do not move at all if I follow the instructions.

Comment: Can you pack your texture, save and post your blend? You can use the following link to post this: [blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/). I think it would be the most relevant to show a solution on your own file.

Answer (score 2):

You may have to re-unwrap your mesh so that the new vertices will confine to the newer state of the mesh. You can do this by pressing U > Reset > Unwrap.