# How to delete the overlapped vertices in a 3D model?

Tags: vertices

As you can see the image below, it is a human head model unwrapped in the `UV/Image Editor`. The selected vertices should be the overlapped vertices but I cannot delete them just by pressing <kbd>Delete</kbd> key. I can just delete it in the `3D View`. However, it is difficult to select them in the `3D View`. So, I want to ask that how to easily delete those overlapped vertices?

**Unwrapped 3D Human Head in `UV/Image Editor`**
[image]

Comment: Maybe related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23354/uv-unwrapping-a-modified-model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solving with "Keep UV and edit mode mesh selection in sync" Option

In the UV Editor window, if you enable the <kbd>Keep UV and edit mode mesh selection in sync</kbd> option [image], then the vertices you select in the *UV Editor* will also be selected in the 3D edit window.

The location of <kbd>Keep UV and edit mode mesh selection in sync</kbd>:
[image]

### Action Demo

You can then go to the *3D window* and delete them.
Don't forget to disable the <kbd>Keep UV and edit mode mesh selection in sync</kbd> option afterwards.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not certain if this is what you're looking for, but if you go into edit mode with `tab`, then select every vertice (by pressing `a`) and in the tool panel (press `t` to toggle), select *remove doubles*. That will remove vertices that closely overlap.